# How to use existing classes in a model without polluting them with 'IDs'?

Tags: entity-framework

I have a couple of classes that are responses fetched from a web service, want to include them in my model but without changing them as they should solely represent service responses, *nothing else*.

How would one achieve this beside duplicating these classes and adding an *id* to them ?

Comment: you have to have pk for entity framework.

Comment: Each entry in an entity framework needs to have a unique identifier, this is normally an Id field, but you can use whatever the primary key is for your responses.

Comment: Maybe you should have a different set of classes for working with the database than the ones you use in your webservice? Look up DTO - Data Transfer Objects. You could try automapper to initialize your DTOs based on entities.

Comment: Excellent, I've found automapper two days ago and it's a real time saver.